# Python error when getting absolute value from a cell while using function

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have below code. It is part of bigger code and i am just providing a snippet to show the problem. When i run below code i get the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'`. `df['URL'].values[0]` runs fine. I want copy text values from URL field into new field called pdf_text and i want to do this one value at a time. Therefore I am using a function. In my real code, i take values from URL column and open those files and do further processing.

```
sales = [{'account': 'credit cards', 'Jan': '150 jones', 'Feb': '200 .jones', 'URL': 'ea2018-001.pdf'},
         {'account': '1',  'Jan': 'Jones', 'Feb': '210', 'URL': ''},
         {'account': '1',  'Jan': '50',  'Feb': '90',  'URL': 'ea2017-104.pdf' }]
df = pd.DataFrame(sales)

def pdf2text(url):

    url=url.values[0]

    return url

#        
abc= (df.assign(pdf_text = df['URL'].apply(pdf2text)))
```

Comment: Why do you think `. values` is necessary? Did you try simply removing it? The error is pretty clear...

Answer (score 0):

You just want the name of the PDF without the file extension?

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> sales = [{'account': 'credit cards', 'Jan': '150 jones', 'Feb': '200 .jones', 'URL': 'ea2018-001.pdf'},
...          {'account': '1',  'Jan': 'Jones', 'Feb': '210', 'URL': ''},
...          {'account': '1',  'Jan': '50',  'Feb': '90',  'URL': 'ea2017-104.pdf' }]
>>> 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(sales)
>>> df.head()

          Feb        Jan             URL       account
0  200 .jones  150 jones  ea2018-001.pdf  credit cards
1         210      Jones                             1
2          90         50  ea2017-104.pdf             1


>>> df['your_column'] = df.URL.map(lambda x: x.split(".")[0])
>>> df.head()


          Feb        Jan             URL       account your_column
0  200 .jones  150 jones  ea2018-001.pdf  credit cards  ea2018-001
1         210      Jones                             1            
2          90         50  ea2017-104.pdf             1  ea2017-104
>>>
```

Comment: no. I am not looking for files names without extensions. I am trying to read each pdf and copy its content into a new column. Before opening and reading PDFs, i would like to see if the file exists. To check that i am using `os.path.exists`. But if i use `os.path.exists(url)`, it returns wrong results as 'url' contains unnecessary stuff like `dtype:object`

Answer (score 0):

It raises `ValueError` because `url` is a string (not whole series) and you try to get `values` attribute from string object.

In your case when you use `apply` for series, your function `pdf2text` on each iteration takes pdf file name as the argument.

```
df['URL'] = df['URL'].apply(pdf2text)
```

is equivalent to

```
urls = []
for url in df['URL']:
    # `url` equals something like this -> 'ea2018-001.pdf'
    urls.append(pdf2text(url))
df['URL'] = pd.Series(urls)
```

but it's slower and unefficient